# CakePHP 4 Routing Regex Pattern

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, routes, frameworks

Hello currently i will do a email verification. For that i have in my `UsersController` the method `verify`

```
public function verify($userid, $code)
    {
        //...
    }
```

Now on my routing i have these, from the cookbook Routing 3.8:

```
$builder->connect('/users/verify/:userid/:code', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'verify'])
        ->setPatterns(['userid' => '^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$']);
```

In my Mind only numbers could pass the `userid`, but when i enter some letters and so, it pass throu and i could display it. Should there be an error? In my Mind yes, cause there are not numbers.

Comment: That route shouldn't match anything. You're not supposed to use `^` and `$`, given that the patterns will be inserted into capture groups of a larger regex. That being said, there's probably other routes matching your URL, please show your all your routes. btw, whenever you have routing problems, check what routes are connected in which order via [**the routes console command**](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/console-commands/routes.html): `bin/cake routes`

Comment: @ndm Yes thats true, saddly after i comment it, i removed the ```$builder->fallbacks();``` And that all the routes, here at https://pastebin.com/vjs2zDy7